# Can an electric circuit board have more electrons than protons?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrons, charge, protons

Current flows from $+$ to $-$ but electrons go the opposite direction.

When I connect the GND of a positive charged electric circuit board to earth, then the board accepts electrons from the earth until the board is neutral.

But let's look at another situation where

1. the GND of a neutral board is not connected to anything
2. I am negatively charged, after rolling and jumping on the carpet for a while

(1) What happens when I touch the $GND$ of the board? Will the board accept extra electrons from me until the board and I are at the same potential. (Both negatively charged.)

(2) If so, what happens when I stop touching $GND$ and I connect GND to earth again? Then, can the board donate the extra electrons back to earth?
Isn't there a lot of circuitry (like diodes and stuff) controlling the direction of current towards $GND$ and (since electrons go the opposite direction) thus preventing the electrons going towards earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes. There is leakage, and if you've charged yourself up statically, you stand a good chance of blowing diodes and transistors on either 1 or 2.

That's why there are such things as [*antistatic devices*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antistatic_device).

Comment: (1) Not quite: Marty and the board likely have different capacitances, so the board will accept electrons until Marty and the board have _common potential_, but not necessarily equal charge.

Comment: @mike-dunlavey Thanks. Yes, things can get damaged, but before thinking of that, i am trying to understand some principles. So, it is true that when my body carries more electrons than protons, the surplus of electrons flows into the board, when i touch GND? Until there is zero potential between me and the board? Even when the board is neutral and not in need of any electrons?

Comment: @Marty: Right. Diodes are not simple one-way valves. Actually the current flow through them is exponential in voltage. So if the voltage is negative, they still leak. And transistors are just more complicated diodes.

Comment: @Marty: [*check it out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode#Current.E2.80.93voltage_characteristic). Also [*Khan Academy.*](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/electrical-engineering/ee-semiconductor-devices/ee-diode/v/ee-diode)